# How do i calculate the location of Turtle on the screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsIqM.png)

```
#Need to figure out turtle's location.
#Need to know it's x/z location in a variable and it's y co-ordinate in another variable seperatley to the x/z co-ordinate
```

I need something like
TurtleX = ...
TurtleY = ...

so I can use these in my game.

Comment: Don't post images of code. Code should be posted into the question itself as formatted text, i.e. code blocks. Read [mre] about what needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, try this

```
>>> turtle.pos()     # -> (x, y)
>>> turtle.xcor()    # -> x
>>> turtle.ycor()    # -> y
```

If you need more info i`m strongly recommend this [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.color)

Comment: Great! is there a way to have these stored as variables? It's fine if not.

Comment: of course! `x = turtle.xcor()`

Comment: The value doesn't change when the Turtle moves! Is it meant to?

Comment: just read documentation, man.